# How to handle questions with a title that turns out to be invalid?

Tags: discussion, questions, title

I recently asked a question on Stack Overflow, "[Why does NumPy's random function seemingly display a pattern in its generated values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50293656/5695018)"

Reading the title, you would obviously assume that NumPy has something going on in its random function, but it turns out my problem is arising from a different library and the problem has nothing to do with NumPy although it seemed like that to be at first glance.

What would be the most appropriate course of action to take in a situation like this?

1. Leave it be, potentially misleading future askers.
2. Modify the title to reflect the new discovery.
3. Change the title and the body of the question to reflect the new discovery.

I feel like option two would be the most logical since option three seems a bit extreme and options one seems like it could confuse people.

Comment: It really depends on whether the question already has answers that would be invalidated if you changed the question ... if there are such answers then the question should not be changed (instead just ask a new question) ... if there are no answers then feel free to change the question.

Comment: It is fine, don't change it.  If you knew that it was caused by the other library then you probably would not have asked the question. Intention here is for other programmers to make the same mistake and find the Q+A back.

Comment: @HansPassant This seems like too localised an issue to be useful. I'd imagine if the question cannot be restructured, then it should be closed as Off Topic > "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, **this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.**..."

Comment: "Reading the title, you would obviously assume that NumPy has something going on in its random function..." No, actually, my first assumption is that they're probably using it wrong or not understanding the results. When you have something as widely used as numpy, a reasonable first guess is that it's probably working correctly.

Comment: I found only modifying the title to be the best case. It reflects the state of the problem when you encountered it, best, while still maximizing searchability and future use.

Comment: In your case I edited your question to reflect that the problem stems from PIL, and not the numpy function, so that future readers of the title are not mislead, while people encountering the same problem as you will likely still find the answer.

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful: agreed, putting the specific cause of the problem (rather than just the observed symptom) makes people think "oh, I didn't realize X could cause Y, maybe I do have that problem" when they see the title.  And it makes it much better for linking in comments / answers to other questions, and as a duplicate target.

Comment: I read your question right after you sent it, before any answer. I loved the "plot twist". That's a pretty nice question and I think it should stay as it is.

Comment: After you have received answers, you should be very hesitant to drastically change the title (or body) because the changes might invalidate existing answers, which is a big no-no. If you have not received answers yet, feel free to change it as much as you want.

Answer (score 4):

People don't usually read SO titles and then assume things about libraries based on that. They usually first find something odd with the library, and *only then* they search to find what's going on. Are they more likely to search for apparent patterns in NumPy, or rounding errors in Pil?

I think you title does a good job at outlining the apparent behavior (that others are more likely to search for) and leading anyone who encounters the same thing to an answer that explains the true reason.

Answer (score 2):

2)/ 3) Edit the title to be more accurate (without invalidating existing answers):

*Is NumPy's random function displaying a pattern in its generated values?*

Generally all you need to do is rewrite to question the premise i.e. *"Is X happening here?"* instead of *"Why is X happening?"* . As long as that doesn't invalidate answers (it shouldn't)

Answer (score 0):

#### General Editing Guidance:

If anything you edit the title, if appropriate, you should never edit a question to change the intent of the question, that invalidates the existing answers and less importantly comments

Then tag it correctly, for example, with the [pil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pil) tag in the tags, not the title, after the solution is found if new tags are appropriate and remove any inappropriate tags.

## In your specific case I would leave everything as it is.

Comment: While adding appropriate tags after the answer is found may be helpful it does little to address the issue of what to do until then. It's reasonable to ask **if** it is because of the PIL but incorrect to say that's the answer. Never add all the tags that might be the answer, it wastes people's time sifting through your noise and clogs the results with incorrect returns.

Comment: @Rob - the entire point of the site being editable or edits suggested by everyone is to edit other's posts to make them better for everyone as soon as they require editing. Incorrect tags before the correct answer is deveined is not a huge issue if it is an issue at all.

Answer (score -2):

Your title is valid.

When you encountered the problem, you *thought* it was because of Numpy's random generation. So your title reflects the problem you had *at the time of asking*.

Now that it's solved, you do know that the problem comes from another library, but this information is (part of) the *solution* / *the answer*.

So I think it's totally valid to have:

> Question title: Why do I have this problem with library X + code Y?
>
> Answer: The problem comes in fact from underlying library Z because ...

---

Another argument: in your precise case, I think it's good to keep the original title for future reference.
Example: someone using Numpy could experience the same issue, and then they would google `numpy random generation pattern`, and then they will find your question, with its original title, ... and finally discover the problem comes from `PIL`.
On the other hand, if you change the title and remove the reference to Numpy, this user wouldn't find it.